# Looking for some references for embedded telecom board

Tags: embedded, board

I am involved with an embedded software development for telecom industry. I have zero experience before with such embedded hardware devices.

I got a network processor board, which is featured in switching pipeline engines. Besides the board, there is also an accessory board called "piggy" (seems for ethernet connetion), and another serial line connection.

I am completely lost about these boards and serial line connections. what they are used for? I tried to use google to find some useful introduction or materials but failed. Can anyone point out what this piggy board is used for? Any good references or books that explain about this?

Comment: A photograph or circuit diagram of the board would help us. Can you see the names of any of the chips?

Comment: @Joby - Help us do what?  I'm not sure this is a real question. Part numbers/manufacturers of the boards would at least give us a clue on where to help and what's really being asked.

Comment: Help us identify the purpose of the board

Comment: hi, Joby, thanks for the reply. it is a Marvell Prestera for switch.

Answer (score 3):

The Marvell prestera chips are 10Gbit Ethernet switches used for high throughput telecommunications packet switching.  It is unlikely that you'll be able to use them for anything other than their intended use, which is essentially moving Ethernet packets around a network, very, very quickly.

Not sure what the "piggy" is without more information.